# Python step by step telnetlib output message

Tags: python, telnetlib

I am working on configuring an ip telephone using python.I can access the ip telephone via telnet, but i want use python.

my code:

```
user = "admin"
password = "admin"
tn = telnetlib.Telnet("192.168.1.191",23)
output = tn.read_until("Login:")
tn.write("admin".encode("ascii")+ b"\r\n")
tn.read_until("Password:")
tn.write("admin".encode("ascii")+ b"\r\n")
tn.write("help".encode("ascii")+ b"\r\n")
output = tn.read_all()
tn.close()
print output
```

but this does not work as it results in an infinite loop without printing any output.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html#telnetlib.Telnet.read_all) `read_all` blocks until the connection is closed. You'd probably be better off figuring out what the last line of output should look like (a prompt maybe?) and using `read_until` like you've been doing. You can also look into [read_eager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html#telnetlib.Telnet.read_eager), [read_very_eager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html#telnetlib.Telnet.read_very_eager) or [read_some](https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html#telnetlib.Telnet.read_some).

Comment: Thank you , read_some() is worked.:
Code :
Sorry not add code

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it helped. Here on stackoverflow, it is general practice to "accept" and answer (to accept an answer, simply click the check-mark to the left of an answer) if it helped solve your problem. Also, if you feel so inclined, you could also upvote an answer (to upvote an answer simply click the "up" arrow to the left of an answer). Doing this helps the people answering your questions feel better about doing so as we are volunteers and work only for the reputation that upvotes and accepted answers provide.